# Почему после применения append пустой исходный код

Tags: jquery, append

Помогите разобраться, с помощью jquery вставляю в select option но в исходном коде этих самых option нет. В браузере option добавляются и показываются. А так как их нет в исходном коде то и форма улетает пустая при отправке на сервер. 
Насколько я правильно понимаю что без перезагрузки тут не обойтись? то есть когда DOM уже выстроен то уже не изменить его? 
А как же мне тогда решить задачу?

Сам код

```
$.get('/getcitys?city_id=' + city_id, function(data){
  $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){

  $('#citys').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+ subcatObj.city +'</option>');

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы путаете то место, где вам нужно смотреть добавленное через `append()`. Если вы посмотрите исходный код страницы, в любом браузере, то там действительно будет тот код, который отдал веб-сервер, и ничего более - это то, что браузер получает на входе и после уже начинает выполнять.

Чтобы же посмотреть то, что браузер в итоге скомпилирует, вам нужно смотреть инспектор, в случае Хрома он вызывается либо из контекстного меню `Просмотреть код`, либо по `F12`. В других браузерах аналогично. Именно тут вы увидите сгенерированную браузером и вашими скриптами DOM-модель.

Пустая форма у вас улетает наверняка из-за ошибки в коде, обрабатывающем ее заполнение и отправку.

Comment: Станислав спасибо за разъяснение! а то уже начал думать что не логично получается. Сейчас займусь просмотром кода. Может пойму где ошибка.

Comment: @jaans не вопрос, и не стесняйтесь отмечать ответ как верный ;) Если будут вопросы по коду, создайте еще один, отдельный вопрос, уже с описанием конкретно кода отправки, формы и всего такого.

Comment: Посмотрел в Firefox Develop да все правильно во вкладке Инспектор действительно браузер генерирует все правильно. Посмотрю почему не отправляется на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз все нашел ошибку. Все работает.